# VSCode - Svelte Autocomplete issue

Tags: visual-studio-code, svelte

Why my svelte autocomplete in VSCode producing something like this

```
import App__SvelteComponent_ from './App.svelte'
```

It supposed to be

```
import App from './App.svelte'
```